# Sitecore Commerce CM Server MongoDB.Driver.MongoDuplicateKeyException

Tags: xdb, mongodb, sitecore-commerce

We are setting up Sitecore Commerce with Sitecore 8.1 using a CM + CD Server on Azure and experiencing the below error in our logs

For some reason on the CM server we are receiving the following error every 10 seconds with the same guids each time

I can see it somehow relates to a duplicate key error index but in similar examples online ContactId: BinData actually has a guid as well i.e. ContactId: BinData(3, 8610726C96B0D4499D41A8041F4138BC)

> **ManagedPoolThread #16 14:34:18 ERROR** An invalid contact transition document related to contact {7794159B-9876-473D-94D6-9595E8330D0E} was found in the AutomationStates collection. The document was ignored.
>
> **ManagedPoolThread #16 14:34:18 WARN**  HasEmptyCartCondition could not find cart.  ShopName: Elle, UserId: {7794159B-9876-473D-94D6-9595E8330D0E}, ExternalId: {b3277b55-ada4-407b-a2cd-a9bb0886441b}
>
> **ManagedPoolThread #16 14:34:18 WARN**  SetCartStatusAction could not find cart.  ShopName: Elle, UserId: {7794159B-9876-473D-94D6-9595E8330D0E}, ExternalId: {b3277b55-ada4-407b-a2cd-a9bb0886441b}
>
> **ManagedPoolThread #16 14:34:18 WARN**  TriggerCartAbandonedOutcome could not find cart.  ShopName: Elle, UserId: {7794159B-9876-473D-94D6-9595E8330D0E}, ExternalId: {b3277b55-ada4-407b-a2cd-a9bb0886441b}
>
> **ManagedPoolThread #16 14:34:18 WARN**  Automation context generation 1 could not be saved for contact 7794159b-9876-473d-94d6-9595e8330d0e. This automation context has already been saved.
>
> **Exception: MongoDB.Driver.MongoDuplicateKeyException**
>   Message: WriteConcern detected an error ''. (Response was { "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: analytics.AutomationStates.$*id*  dup key: { : { ContactId: BinData, Generation: 1 } }", "code" : 11000, "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 19499, "ok" : 1.0 }).
>   Source: MongoDB.Driver
>
> at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.WriteOpcodeOperationBase.ReadWriteConcernResult(MongoConnection connection, SendMessageWithWriteConcernResult sendMessageResult)
>
> at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.InsertOpcodeOperation.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
>
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.InsertBatch(Type nominalType, IEnumerable documents, MongoInsertOptions options)
>
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Insert(Type nominalType, Object document, MongoInsertOptions options)
>
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.<>c__DisplayClass32.b__31()
>
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Execute(Action action, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)
>
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Insert(Object value)
>
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.MongoDbAutomationProvider.SaveAutomationContext(AutomationContext modifiedAutomationContext)

Comment: I think the reason you're not seeing the contents of `BinData` is because your version of MongoDB is older compared to Thomas's version [**here**](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/6/t/3469). That logged JSON message you're seeing comes directly from the MongoDB server. I'm sure that `BinData` object actually contains the contact ID `{7794159B-9876-473D-94D6-9595E8330D0E}`.

Comment: I have upgraded mongodb to 2.6.9 and now see the bin data, i still haven't figured out what is causing the issue though